# Border for css shapes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have discovered css shapes and I'm interested is there a way to make border (solid, dotted, dashed) for them ([shapes](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/))?

The first thing that I've though about was to made another shape and put it on the background by z-index (http://jsfiddle.net/gYKSd/), but it makes an effect only as solid border.

HTML:

```
<div class="triangle"></div>
<div class="background"></div>
```

CSS:

```
     .triangle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 14px;
        left: 10px;
        height: 0px;
        width: 0px;
        border-right: 50px solid transparent;
        border-left: 50px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 100px solid red;
        z-index: 0;
}
      .background {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 0px;
        width: 0px;
        border-right: 60px dotted transparent;
        border-left: 60px dotted transparent;
        border-bottom: 120px dotted gray;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

Comment: Basically you can't do that because the elements are made of borders...and a border can't have another border. That's not to say that you can't 'fake it' by adding extra elements but that's not what you asked.

Comment: CSS shapes are a hack. CSS isn't designed for drawing shapes. Sure, use it for basic triangles if you must; everyone else doess. But don't expect it to be able to go one step further, because you can't; the nature of the hack is that that is as good as it gets. If you want something more than that, use the browser's proper graphics tools like SVG.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah sorry i wasn't clear. But I meant tricks to solve this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution (positioning a background div) is about the most workable way you are going to get in CSS because the shapes are not recognized by the browser as shapes.

You can take a square, make copies and rotate them to make a point burst, and it looks like a point burst but as far as the browser is concerned, you have 3 squares, not a point burst, and if you put a border, the borders will be around each square.

You could make small rectangles, rotate them and position them on the edges of your "shape" to create a "border", so yes, it's doable, but for all practical purposes, it's insane.

If you need to draw shapes on the fly, have a look at HTML5 canvas [Intro to canvas drawing](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html).

---

SVG is now a valid option as well [since all recent browsers support it](http://caniuse.com/svg).

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I had given up on svg a while back because of the poor browser support but it looks like this is no longer an issue with recent browsers.

Comment: @Sylverdrag Do you know what is more resource demanding canvas or SVG. Because I have never worked with SVG, but I used to with canvas and it wasn't seemed like something fast.

Comment: @VadimKalinin You would need to test what works for you, but I suspect your performance problem was due to external factors (connexion, etc.) rather than canvas performance. You can see a canvas vs SVG comparison  here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg193983(v=vs.85).aspx#Using_Canvas_AndOr_SVG

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, because what you're doing relies on the fact that the shapes are made from borders.

You can't add borders to what is already a border.

But like you showed in your fiddle, you can emulate another border by having a background shape.

Answer (score 0):

As a few said above....CSS shapes are made with solid borders and the angles of those coming together, so you cannot change the border-style or you would not produce the shape you wanted